# show that $\nu(K)=HK/H$

Tags: group-theory

Dear member kindly help me in following:

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $\nu$ be the canonical homomorphism from $G$ to $G/H$. Let $K$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then show that $\nu(K)=HK/H$.

Comment: Following the usual conventions where $G / H$ denotes the set of *left* cosets of $H$ with representatives in $G$, you probably want to prove that $\nu(K) \cong KH/H$.  Since $H$ is normal in $G$, you have $HK = KH$, but in this other form you can more directly apply the Second Isomorphism Theorem:  http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Second_Isomorphism_Theorem/Groups

Comment: I have never heard of these "usual conventions". In any case, if $H$ is a normal subgroup then $gH = Hg$ for all $g$ so there is no difference between left and right cosets.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since $K \subset HK$, it follows that $\nu(K) \subset \nu(HK)$ and conversely, if $hk \in HK$, then $\nu(hk) = \nu(k) \in \nu(K) \Rightarrow \nu(HK) \subset \nu(K)$. Hence,
$$
\nu(K) = \nu(HK) = HK/H
$$